# HTML table spanning

Tags: html, xhtml

Bit of a simple one here. If I have a table as in [this example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?02) how would I go about adding multiple employee cells? Would I apply a greater `rowspan` to the appropriate location `td`, and/or would I use blank `<td />`s for the 'empty' cell (in this case the location cell)? What if I add another column between the two, would I then add the appropriate `rowspan` to its cells too, or would they be assumed somehow?

Comment: For this purpose, consider using div with css rather than a table.

Comment: But it's definitely tabular content (or at least the final product will be!)

Answer (score 0):

I think a table is appropriate - you're building a table of data that is supposed to have rows, columns, headers etc...

I may not understand exactly what you're trying to do but it sounds like you have multiple employees per location. I wouldn't worry about rowspans at all. Just make additional rows and if the location is the same then leave that <td> empty.

There's not so much a right and wrong way, but I think this is the least complicated way, and that's generally a good thing.

Edit: Forgot to mention- if you add another column between the two I would use empty <td>s for that too if  appropriate. Think of a <td> as a data field. If the data field is empty then the <td> should be empty. If the data field itself makes more sense as two or more combined then *that's* when you should think about spanning between multiple rows or columns.

Comment: Well this is what I have now: http://www.webdevout.net/test?0m
Is this correct? And then I would apply say, `rowspan="2"` to the Eastington `td`?

Comment: I would just use another empty td instead of worrying about rowspan. I assume you are doing this by hand rather than having a script do it? Even then, using an empty td will allow you to quickly copy/paste your basic row structure and make this go quicker for you. Also styling a big huge td might be a little tedious. But yes, your example looks like what I meant.

Comment: My only worry is that individual, blank `td`s will be represented as regular cells -- with the usual border and so forth. It could get unsightly for a large table. Plus I'm not too sure if it'd be correct semantically; John Jones should be associated with the location 'Eastington', not a blank location!

Comment: Those are both valid points and good reasons for using a rowspan. Personally I would probably still do it my way, but a rowspan would be acceptable. One other thing though - upkeep. If you're doing this by hand you will need to remember to always update that rowspan number every time you add or remove rows. With empty tds all you have to do is copy a line and edit the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `rowspan` in the locations which has more than one employee and create a new row for each new employee, adding 1 to the value of the rowspan.
Like this http://www.webdevout.net/test?01G

I think this way is easier to see which location each employee is related to.

But it must have a hundred ways to solve your problem.